# Wordpress Autoptimize not clearing Cache

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, caching, plugins

Having a problem with wordpress plugin Autoptimize. I have made changes in CSS but its not reflecting on the website when I use it via Chrome.

When visiting the same site via Safari the changes are showing. On Chrome even on Incognito the changes don't reflect.

On inspection elements in chrome dev tool, I have noticed the css file being read is a cached Autoptimize file.

I have tried clearing and purging all cache, deleting the plugin. Deleting the Plugin Cache folder yet the same issue.

Comment: Autoptimize (or any other caching plugin) cannot clear the **browser cache**, which is what is clearly happening here in your Chrome browser.